# Number of possible paths of fixed length 'K' between given vertices of an undirected graph

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory

I want to find the number of different possible paths of a fixed-length "K" between two vertices of an undirected graph, I saw many implementations of it using the Adjacency matrix but is there any way to do it without an adjacency matrix? If there is a way, please give some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem I think that adjacency matrices are your best bet as you can compute many answers at the same time making the overall algorithm faster. If you want to implement a solution using an adjacency list I would try a brute force-recursive approach but do note that it will definitely be slower than the adjacency matrix one.